# RTABmap corrupted database

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everytime when I perfrom SLAM with RTABMAP, I get a map with some warning like:

```
Memory.cpp:1746::forget() Less signatures transferred (3) than added (4)! The working memory cannot decrease in size
```

But when I start the localization part (on a 2nd time), the database gets corrupted and I get this error everytime:

```
VWDictionary.cpp:616::addWordRef() Not found word
```

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328500/rtabmap-corrupted-database/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For the first warning, it is because memory management is enabled and for some reasons rtabmap cannot transfer enough locations to long-term memory to decrease Working Memory size. Unless you understand very well how memory management is done, I suggest to disable it while you are debugging the mapping. To do so, make sure parameter `Rtabmap/TimeThr` and `Rtabmap/MemoryThr` are 0 (by default they are 0).

For the error "`VWDictionary.cpp:616::addWordRef() Not found word`", it means the database has some data missing (because for example the database was not correctly closed). To repair the database, we have a tool called `rtabmap-recovery`:

```
$ rtabmap-recovery ~/.ros/rtabmap.db
```

To make sure the database is correctly saved, after doing ctrl-c on terminal that started rtabmap, you should see:

```
rtabmap: Saving database/long-term memory...done! (located at /home/user/.ros/rtabmap.db, 76 MB)
```

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-15**:
@matlabbe so how can I properly close after finishing the SLAM?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-17**:
I updated the answer